# URL rewrite problem

Tags: 7, views, uri

I face a problem with *URL rewrite* in views. In the *Re-Write Results* section I choose "*Output this field as a link*" and provide the following link path;

`node/[nid]&month=[field_month]`

(nid is the node id, field_month is a date field with a special format of 'Y-m')

The relevant *URL* should be something like this `node/39&month=2012-02`.

The problem is that *Drupal* encodes the *URL* and in response I receive

`node/39%26month%3D2012-02`, which is unusable. I use *Drupal 7.12* and *views 7.x-3.1*.

Any suggestions how can I overcome this?

Comment: If you are comfortable with php, you could do this yourself in a views template

Comment: Since the & and + characters are Reserved characters in a URL, it looks as if Views is automatically translating them to their code equivalents. How will you be using the information in the URL?

Comment: yeah, are you sure you don't need node/39?month=2012-02

Answer (score 1):

See @MotoTribe's / @Ashlar's comment for a clue. `node/1/&foo=bar` is not a valid URL. An unescaped `&` character is only legal in the query portion of the URL, but not the path part. The path and query are separated by the `?` character and since your URL doesn't have a `?`, the `&` must be in the path part of your URL. As a result, views automatically escapes it for you.

I suspect you just want `node/[nid]?foo=bar`. In that case, views will NOT escape the `?` or `=`.

The `&` character is only used to separate queries when more than one appear in the query section of the URL.